# dropdown button in Drawer flutter

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu, navigation-drawer, flutter-dropdownbutton

I try to add dropdown button in drawer header but I face issue

dropdown button

[image: 1]

this is my code

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
type here
```

import 'package:test/Screens/change_password_screen.dart';
import 'package:test/Screens/login_screen.dart';

class MainDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
const MainDrawer({super.key});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

```
return Drawer(
  
  width: 250,
  child: ListView(
    children: <Widget>[
      
      DrawerHeader(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
            image: const DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage("assets/images/logo.png"),
            )),
        child: const Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: Text(
            "Example@hotmail.com",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 14.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        
      ),
 
      const Divider(
        color: Colors.black, //color of divider
        height: 10, //height spacing of divider
        thickness: 1, //thickness of divier line
      ),
      ListTile(
        leading: Image.asset(
          "assets/images/exampla.png",
        ),
        title: const Text(
          'exampla',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontSize: 14.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
          ),
        ),
        onTap: null,
      ),
      const Divider(
        color: Colors.black, //color of divider
        height: 10, //height spacing of divider
        thickness: 1, //thickness of divier line
      ),
      ListTile(
        leading: Image.asset(
          "assets/images/examplb.png",
        ),
        title: const Text(
          'examplb',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontSize: 14.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
          ),
        ),
        onTap: null,
      ),
      const Divider(
        color: Colors.black, //color of divider
        height: 10, //height spacing of divider
        thickness: 1, //thickness of divier line
      ),
      ListTile(
        leading: Image.asset(
          "assets/images/examplc.png",
        ),
        title: const Text(
          'examplc',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontSize: 14.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
          ),
        ),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => const ExamplzScreen()),
          );
        },
      ),
      const Divider(
        color: Colors.black, //color of divider
        height: 10, //height spacing of divider
        thickness: 1, //thickness of divier line
      ),
      ListTile(
        leading: Image.asset(
          "assets/images/logout.png",
        ),
        title: const Text(
          'Log out',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontSize: 14.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
          ),
        ),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const LoginScreen()),
          );
        },
      ),
      const Divider(
        color: Colors.black, //color of divider
        height: 10, //height spacing of divider
        thickness: 1, //thickness of divier line
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

}
}

I try to add dropdown but I face error in setState

List itemsList = [
'1',
'2'
];
String? selectedItem = '1';

Container(

```
         padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: 25.0, vertical: 0.0),
         child: SizedBox(
              height: 40,

              child: DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                    width: 1,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ))),
                  value: selectedItem,
                  items: itemsList
                      .map((item) => DropdownMenuItem(
                            value: item,
                            child: Text(
                              item,
                            ),
                          ))
                      .toList(),
                  onChanged: (item) => setState(() => selectedItem = item)),
            ),
       ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your MainDrawer widget is **Statelesswidget** you will need to
update it to **Statefulwidget** so state can be changed with **SetState** method.
and also share the error if it's still gives error.